# Add data to existing excel sheet

Tags: python

Some data needs to be added to existing excel sheet. Here is the code. It is not working with some errors. I am Mechanical Engineer facing some issues with this code

```
    import openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
    from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook 

    #Existing exceel sheet

    book_ro=load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical\\Data\\Wear_sumary.xlsx")
    sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")

    #Following is the Data that needs to be added to that sheet

    c1 = sheet['R1']   #R1 represents Column R, Row-1
    c1.value = "Average Disp"
    c2 = sheet['R2']   #R1 represents Column R, Row-2
    c2.value = "=AVERAGE(D2:E2)"
    c3 = sheet['S1']   #S1 represents Column S, Row-1
    c3.value = "Gap"
    c4 = sheet['S2']   #S2 represents Column S, Row-2
    c4.value = "=D3/E4"

    wb.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical_test\\Data\\Wear_summary.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please edit the post to include the errors.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the help. You have reduced my tension.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load workbook, then load your sheet (`sheet=wb["Sheet1"]`). You can assign the values directly to the cells by accessing using `sheet['R1']`. Below code should work.

Please check : (case sensitive) 
1. Your path is correct
2. Your excel workbook name is correct &
3. Your sheet name is correct('sheet1')

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Existing exceel sheet
wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical\\Data\\Wear_summary.xlsx")
# sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

sheet['R1'] = "Average Disp"
sheet['R2'] = "=AVERAGE(D2:E2)"
sheet['S1'] = "Gap"
sheet['S2'] = "=D3/E4"

wb.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical\\Data\\Wear_summary.xlsx")
```

> Edit: you can use the below code to update columns 'R' and 'S' from 2 to 24,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical\\Data\\Wear_summary.xlsx")
sheet=wb["Sheet1"]

sheet['R1'] = "Average Disp"
sheet['S1'] = "Gap"

# for loop will fill values for 'R' and 'S' from row 2 to row 24
for i in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
        sheet['R{}'.format(i)] = '=AVERAGE(D{}:E{})'.format(i,i)
        sheet['S{}'.format(i)] = '=D{}/E{}'.format(i+1,i+2)

wb.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mechanical\\Data\\Wear_summary.xlsx")

# please ensure the path, filename and worksheet name are correct
```

`sheet.max_row+1` will fill the values till the current last row, i.e. if you have values till 50th row , it will fill till 50th

Comment: Sir Thank u for replying and its working fine.I need one suggestion,Kindly help. The data contains values until row 24 upto column Q. Is there a way when i run the python code column 'R' & 'S' fills value until row24. Right now only row2 the values gets filled.

Comment: @ANANDPATIL, if you have values in 'D' and 'E' only upto row 24, then the last two values in column 'S' will be `#DIV/0!`

Comment: @ANANDPATIL please upvote and select as correct answer, if its working correctly

Comment: Just click the '^' and ✓  symbol

Comment: Upvote done.Sir final doubt right now i have values until row24. If in a new sheet if i have values until row50. How to make changes in code such that after i run code coloumn R and S gets filled until respective rows accordingly. or should i keep entering start and end of row in this line "for i in range(2,25):"?

Comment: @ANANDPATIL updated , current one will fill values till the last row , changed `range(2,25)` to `range(2,sheet.max_row+1)`

Comment: Thank You very Much. U have helped me a lot Sir.